# Google Script email also being sent to account owner?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have a problem with a Google MCC Script I have. It's set up to run every day in the early hours of the morning, do some processing, and email out a result, using Google Scripts' built in MailApp.sendEmail function.

The problem is that, while the email is sent successfully, I'm also recieving messages in the inbox of the email address which owns the MCC account along the lines of

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>  MCC_account@example.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:  The email account that you
>   tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the
>   recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces.

with the 'Original Message' appended below that indicating it is indeed the message the Script has sent. Here's my code:

```
function main() {
  var accountSelector = MccApp.accounts();
  var accountIterator = accountSelector.withIds('###-###-###').get();
  if(accountIterator.hasNext()){
    var account = accountIterator.next();
    MccApp.select(account);

    var data = getData();
    sendEmail(data);

  } else Logger.log("Error: no accounts found");
}

function sendEmail(data){
  var name = 'name';
  var bodytext = 'body';
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'receiver-inbox@example.com',
    name: 'Google Adwords Scripts',
    replyTo: 'do-not-reply@example.com',
    subject: 'SUBJECT',
    attachments: [{fileName: name, mimeType: 'text/csv', content: data}],
    body: bodytext
  });
}
```

So, to clarify, the MCC account is owned by one email address, the script doesn't reference that at all, but I'm recieving the email not only in the target mailbox but also a failed delivery message in the owner inbox.

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently this is a known issue with AdWords Scripts:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-scripts/SJtNW_wuArI

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you are running another copy of the script that is sending these emails. Go to your Google Account settings here and [revoke access](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) to the other script.

If you have multiple Google accounts, do a scan for all the accounts.

Comment: I have revoked access to all scripts that have mail permissions other than this one, but I doubt this is the case, from the Original Message Appended Below in the bounce email, it's clear the email that has bounced is the same one that was sent to the target inbox as well.

I will report back if the access revocation has worked.

Comment: I got the same bounce email this morning, so it's not a problem with another script.